# FabricJS object is not selectable/clickable/resizable in top left corner (React + FabricJs)

Tags: reactjs, fabricjs

I have `FabricJs` canvas. And I have multiple objects outside canvas. When I click on object, it appears in Canvas. I am not doing anything else with this object programmatically.

Here is part of code that add image to Canvas (it is React code):

```
const { state, setState } = React.useContext(Context);
const { canvas } = state;
...
const handleElementAdd = (event, image) => {     
    const imageSize = event.target.childNodes[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    const imageUrl = `/storage/${image.src}`;
    new fabric.Image.fromURL(imageUrl, img => {
        var scale = 1;      
    if (img.width > 100) {
      scale = 100/img.width;
    }
    var oImg = img.set({
      left:  state.width / 2 - img.width * scale, 
      top:  state.height / 2 - img.height * scale, 
      angle: 0})
    .scale(scale);       
   
    canvas.add(oImg).renderAll.bind(canvas);
    canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
  });
  };
      ...       
  <div              
          key={img.name}
          onClick={(e) => handleElementAdd(e, img)}
          className={buttonClass}
        >
```

It appears, I can drag and drop, resize, select it. However, when my object is placed in top left corner of canvas, it is not clickable, resizable etc. I can select larger area and then object is selected, but it doesn't respond to any events like resize, select etc.

Not sure where to look at.
I read that if coordinates are changed programmatically `object.setCoord()` to object can help, but in this case I do not understand where to put it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put (call) object.setCoords() each time you have modified the object, or moved the object. So, you can call it on mouseUp event of the canvas.

You can write a function naming "moveObject" in which you get the object you are trying to move/moved/updated. And then just selectedObject.setCoords().

Then call that function inside     canvas.on('selection:updated', e => {----})